# On this div slideshow there is inconsistent margin jumping after margin-left slide.It starts on the second cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

Right now when you click the next button you get a smooth animation but when you get to the copy of the div that was detached when it went out of view on the left side and appended to the wrapper the sliding animation gets a little choppy. I want it to always be smooth like at the beginning. I'm guess that the problem is that I'm adding `.css({"margin-left" : "5px"})` and that is messing up with the original sliding functionality -- `$(".element").eq(0).css({"margin-left" : "-245px"})` I had to add the margin 5px otherwise the newly attached divs didn't show any margins. (they were staking up on each other)

```
$(document).ready( function(){
        $(".next").on("click", function(){
            $(".element").eq(0).css({"margin-left" : "-245px"}).delay(1000).queue(function(next){
                $(this).css({"margin-left" : "5px"}).appendTo(".wrapper");
                 $(this).dequeue();
            })
        })
 });
```

css:

```
.mgcont{
    margin:5% auto;
    width:970px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 2px solid gray;
}
.wrapper{
    /*overflow: hidden;*/

    white-space: nowrap;
    width:960px;

}
.element{
    width: 240px;
    height: 300px;
    background: tomato;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    transition: margin-left 1s;
}
.prev{
    float: right;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="mgcont">
    <button class="next">next</button>
    <button class="prev">PREV</button>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="element">1</div>
        <div class="element">2</div>
        <div class="element">3</div>
        <div class="element">4</div>
        <div class="element">5</div>
        <div class="element">6</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like it's being caused by the fact that, based on the initial mark-up, the `inline-block` styling is an adding an extra ~4-5 pixels after each block, [as discussed here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).  Something about the jQuery append, however, is adjusting the mark-up so that the extra padding goes away on round two (probably by stripping space between tags).

It looks like you were compensating for the initial extra padding by making the negative margin 5 more pixels (`{"margin-left" : "-245px"}`) than their actual width (`width: 240px`) should require.  On the first go-around, this made the "next" block appear to land more or less in its place. But on subsequent loops, it moved the elements "too far", hence the jumping back.

To solve:

1. First step would be to change the negative margin effect to use the same width as the blocks, i.e. `{"margin-left" : "-240px"}`.  However, this alone makes the first loop have a bit of jumpiness (though not as noticeable, in my opinion), so:
2. Next would be to deal with the extra padding.  I guess you have a few options.:

   - The easiest would be to just use `float: left;` instead of `display: inline-block`.  Float doesn't have the extra-padding problem.  But if floats create more issues, you could try:
   - Using a different CSS hack described in the above link, e.g. set .wrapper to `font-size: 0;` and .element "back" to `font-size: 16px`. Bleh.
   - Re-writing the mark-up by hand. Yawn-and-a-half.  And not always possible.
   - Replicate the re-write of the mark-up with jQuery, by doing something like this:

     ```
     $(".element").each(function(){
       $(this).appendTo(".wrapper");
     });
     ```

     though that feels hackish too (and I don't know what performance ramifications it may have).